# Magento2 : Product import using GraphQL

Tags: magento2, graphql

Magento Doesn't provide Product import using graphQL. can any one have idea about it and how to import product using GraphQL.?

Answer (score 0):

GraphQl in magento is not used for store management purpose. However you can create a custom resolver that allows admin authorization to import. eg. see [Magento_LoginAsCustomerGraphQl](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/LoginAsCustomerGraphQl/Model/Resolver/RequestCustomerToken.php) module. Also consider a REST api import would be better in terms of performance and developer time.
Bulk API in REST is really good if you want to import products through APIs. There is a very good tutorial in [devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/tutorials/bulk-configurable-product/config-product-intro.html) too.

Answer (score -2):

If you get products using GraphQL

Follow the link below:

https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-product-collection-using-graphql-magento-2/

Comment: This is for fetching data